# tensor product of two algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

As an $\mathbb{F}_{2}$-algebra, is $\mathbb{F}_{q} \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_{2}} \mathbb{F}_{2^2} $ isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{q}^2$, where $q = 2^k$ for $k$ is even?

Please give me some idea and some reference.

Answer (score 2):

Writing $\mathbb{F}_{2^2} = \mathbb{F}_2[X] / (X^2 + X + 1),$ it follows that $$\mathbb{F}_q \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_2} \mathbb{F}_{2^2} \cong \mathbb{F}_q[X] / (X^2 + X + 1) \cong \mathbb{F}_q^2,$$ since $X^2 + X + 1$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$ whenever $k$ is even.